# Could I add XmlAdapter to JAXB from runtime (w/o annotation)?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf, jaxb2

In all cases [XmlAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) mentioned in pair with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. Is it possible add my `XmlAdapter` from runtime API (necessary for [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) @XmlJavaTypeAdapter workaround)?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

MOXy offers an XML representation of the JAXB (and MOXy) metadata that can be used as an alternative to annotations:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

This mapping file can be easily leveraged in a JAX-RS environment:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html

This mapping file has the added benefit of allowing multiple mappings to be applied to an object model:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/moxy-extensible-models-multiple.html

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter